# can i assign a javascript function definition to any variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to manipulate values between functions and here am trying to pass one value to function and want's to access that functions resultant value in variable for that what i tried is

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {        
        var rowheader = $('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim();          
        HeaderData(rowheader); 
}
```

```
var result=function HeaderData(header){return header);};
    $(".booked").unbind('click').click(function () {
        alert(result);        
    });<br>
```

then it shows the function definition in alert box like
[image]
so the approach am following is it correct or not?

Comment: you aren't calling `result` or `HeaderData`?

Comment: "Is it correct or not" - only you can tell us whether that is the desired result or not.

Comment: not that suppose to show value which is stored in rowheader  variable

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `alert` is supposed to do. It expects a string as an argument, and if a string wasn't passed, the method implicitly converts the passed argument to a string.

Comment: so the thing am trying is it achievable or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are just get the reference of result. To call result function, it look like this result(header);

```
var result=function HeaderData(header){return header);};
$(".booked").unbind('click').click(function () {
    alert(result("header"));        
});<br>
```

Comment: you can do it in this way:  var result1 = result("header"); now you assign a result function with parameter "header" to result1, and then you can execute result1 by result1();

Comment: in your case, you can assign this HeaderData(rowheader) to a variable, such as var header = HearderData(rowHeader), and then use it  in the unbind click, alert(header());